# How to receive UDP broadcasts with PHP

Tags: php, udp, broadcast

I am trying to receive a repeated UDP broadcast with PHP and display it on a webpage on local host.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I would most likely have a daemon or server process running that would be responsible for receiving the UDP broadcast and appending it to either a file or database (this could be implemented in any language). I would then have a PHP page that either reads the file or queries the database for results and echoing the results on the page.

If you're looking for live updates, then I'd be adding some jQuery/AJAX scripting magic.